# How can I call a function name defined in a literal string in perl?

Tags: perl, function, reference, interpolation

If `$name='name'` why does `$object_ref->$name` work but not `$object_ref->('name')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$obj->$name       # Method call with no args
$obj->name        # Method call with no args
$obj->$name()     # Method call with no args
$obj->name()      # Method call with no args

$sub->('name')    # Sub call (via ref) with one arg.
sub('name')       # Sub call with one arg.
```

Answer (score 11):

In Perl, the symbol `->` has two meanings.  If followed by a bareword `$obj->name` or a scalar `$obj->$name` then `->` means method call.

If instead the `->` is followed by an opening brace, then it is a dereference, according to the following table:

```
$obj->(...) # dereference as code,  which calls the subroutine
$obj->[...] # dereference as array, which accesses an element
$obj->{...} # dereference as hash,  which accesses an element
```

When `->` is dereferencing a value, perl will check to see if the value is either the type indicated by the brace, or if it can be coerced into that type via overloading.  So the `->(` in your example means perl will try to convert `$object_ref` into a code reference, and will probably fail, throwing an error.

If the `->` is a method call, then perl does something like:

```
if (reftype $name eq 'CODE') {  # if $name is code, ignore $object_ref's type
    $name->($object_ref)        # call the coderef in $name, with $object_ref
}                               # followed by any other arguments

elsif (my $code = $object_ref->can($name)) { # otherwise, try to look up the
    # coderef for the method named $name in $object_ref's namespace and then
    $code->($object_ref)  # call it with the object and any other arguments
}
else {die "no method $name on $object_ref"}
```

Just to make things clearer:

```
sub foo {"foo(@_)"}

my $foo = \&foo;

say foo 'bar';     # 'foo(bar)'
say $foo->('bar'); # 'foo(bar)'
say 'bar'->$foo;   # 'foo(bar)'
```

and

```
sub Foo::bar {"Foo::bar(@_)"}
my $obj = bless [] => 'Foo';

my $method = 'bar';

say $obj->bar(1);     # Foo::bar($obj, 1)
say $obj->$method(1); # Foo::bar($obj, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for method calls is `$object->method` or `$object->$method`. The syntax you gave, however, can be used for `$sub_ref->(@param)`.